# How is browsers position altitude defined?

Tags: web-mapping, browser

Looking at the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates/altitude

It says "altitude above sea level in meters". Does this mean it takes into account geoid data of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [w3c specification](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#altitude) (under 'specifications' of your link):

> The altitude attribute denotes the height of the position, specified
>   in meters above the [WGS84] ellipsoid.